ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
I get this error:

ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException: Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown.
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskInternal(String name, String version, String taskList, Type resultType, Object[] parameters) in //src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 121
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskToWorker[TResult](String name, String version, String taskList, Object[] parameters) in //src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 92
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTask[TResult](String name, String version, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 84
at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)

Here is my code:
services.AddSingleton(services =>
{
                var serviceBus = GetValueOrDefaultBase("serviceBus__fullyQualifiedNamespace");               
                return new ServiceBusClient(serviceBus, new DefaultAzureCredential());
});


await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(SenderFunction), content);

await serviceBusRepository.SendMessageAsync(message);

public async Task SendMessageAsync(ServiceBusMessage message)
{
            var serviceBusmessage = new ServiceBusMessage
            {
                Body = new BinaryData(message.Body),
                MessageId = message.MessageId
            };

            if (message.ApplicationProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in message.ApplicationProperties)
                {
                    serviceBusmessage.ApplicationProperties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                }
            }

            await _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusmessage);
}


What is your .net version?

,NET 8 isolated

I am able to send message to service bus using below approach:
Firstly, created function app and then enabled managed identity:

Then In Service Bus ---> Access Control IAM ---> Add Role ---> Data Sender:

Then:

After clicking next, now select the Function app managed identity and then select and then review and create.

Below Function Code worked for me:
Program.cs:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var rith = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(cho =>
    {
        cho.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        cho.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        cho.AddSingleton<ServiceBusClient>(provider =>
        {
            return new ServiceBusClient("rith02.servicebus.windows.net", new DefaultAzureCredential());
        });
    })
    .Build();

rith.Run();

Function.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> ri_lg;
        private readonly ServiceBusClient ri_sc;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, ServiceBusClient sbc)
        {
            ri_lg = logger;
            ri_sc = sbc;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja");

            await TestRith("rith", "Secret!!");
            var rout = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await rout.WriteStringAsync("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return rout;
        }

        private async Task TestRith(string qn, string msg)
        {
            var ri_sen = ri_sc.CreateSender(qn);
            var sbc1 = new ServiceBusMessage(msg);
            await ri_sen.SendMessageAsync(sbc1);
            ri_lg.LogInformation($"Message sent to queue {qn}: {msg}");
        }
    }
}

Output:


This is how I send messages to Service Bus Queue from Azure Function App.
